# Applying style to a parent block depending on the child's state

Tags: css, hide, selector, parent-child, is-empty

With the following block structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="subject"></div>
</div>
```

is it possible to hide (display:none) a `.container` if it's child `.subject` is empty?
Thanks!

Comment: not with CSS, only with JS

Comment: CSS is just for styling not for validation and checking empty things.

Comment: If the element itself is void of children, you *could* use the empty pseudo selector:  `.container:empty { display: none }`.  However, this won't work for your example because it has children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well... you could try to fake it... make title `position: absolute` and for container set `overflow: hidden;` container itself will only be visible if you put something into .subject tag. Like this:
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EbMZP/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll have to use javascript to do this. In jQuery:

```
$(".container").each( function() {
    if ( $(this).children('.subject').html() == '' ) {
           $(this).hide();
    }
} );
```

Example at: http://jsfiddle.net/m5jjs/

Comment: i would use children instead of find

Answer (score 1):

`:empty` psuedo class can be used if element has no node but you have. Need JS though.

```
$(".container *") {
   if($.trim($(this).html()).length == 0 && $.trim($(this).text()).length == 0 ) {
     $(".container").css({ "display" : "none" });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible in pure CSS in any browser I know of.

There is a jQuery plugin [cssParentSelector](https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector) polyfill for the upcoming *parent* selector in [CSS Selectors Level 4](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/21/sneak-peek-future-selectors-level-4/) if you already have a jQuery dependency in the project.